# Display action Link conditionally in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hello I have an action link on a view but I only want it to be shown conditionally. In my case the "Order status" can be .. pending, released, closed.

I want the actionlink to only display on the page when the status is not equal to pending. 
Here is my action link

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Revert to Pending", "Revert", "SalesOrders", new { id = @Model.ID }, new {target = "_blank"})
```

I'm not sure if there is some way I can hide it through the controller or view or if this is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Razor logic in your view:

```
@if(Model.status != "Pending")
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Revert to Pending", "Revert", "SalesOrders", new { id = @Model.ID }, new {target = "_blank"})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, since it's just a single line, it can be further simplified like so:

```
@if(Model.status != "Pending")
    @Html.ActionLink("Revert to Pending", "Revert", "SalesOrders", new { id = @Model.ID }, new {target = "_blank"})
```